# Find the minimum set of integers whose sum is greater than a given integer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I am attempting to solve the below question. I solved this question in O(n^2) time complexity. Is there a way to optimize it further and bring the complexity down to O(n) by iterating the array just once?

Given an array of n integers and a number S. I need to find the minimum set of consecutive integers whose sum is greater than the number S. If no such set exists, I will print 0.

Required complexities:
Space complexity-O(1)
Time Complexity-O(n)

Example-

Array A={2,5,4,6,3,9,2,17,1}

S= 17

Output=2

Explanation-

Possible solutions are:-

{2,5,4,6,3}=2+5+4+6+3=20(>18)=5 numbers

{5,4,6,3,9}=27(>18)=5 numbers

{4,6,3,9}=22(>18)-4 numbers

{6,3,9,2}=20=4 numbers

{3,9,2,17}=4 numbers

{9,2,17}=3 numbers

{2,17}=2 numbers

so, minimum =2 numbers. output=2.

Comment: Any attempt at solving this independently?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow does not do your homework for you.

Comment: I solved it with time complexity O(n^2) but I am unable to optimize it further. This problem can be solved in O(n) time complexity without using additional array.

Comment: *I solve it with ...*: please show your algorithm (in your question) and your attempts to improve it.

Comment: Also indicate whether the integers can be negative or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all integers are non-negative and *S* is positive, you can use the following algorithm:

Use two indices, one for where the current sequence starts, and another for where it ends. When the sum of that sequence is too small you extend the sequence by incrementing the second index; if the sum is over *S*, you keep track of whether it is the best so far and at the same time remove the first value from the sequence, by incrementing the first index.

Here is the algorithm in more formal pseudo code:

```
n = size(A)
best = n + 1
sum = 0
i = 0

for j = 0 to n - 1:
    sum = sum + A[j]
    while sum > S:
        if j - i + 1 < best:
            best = j - i + 1
        sum = sum - A[i]
        i = i + 1

if best > n:
    best = 0

output best
```

Space complexity is *O(1)* as there are 4 numerical variables involved (not counting the input array), which represents a fixed amount of memory.

Time complexity is *O(n)* as the total number of times the statements in the inner loop execute is never more than *n* (*i* is incremented each time and will never bypass *j*).